# How to make a dynamic import command from one sheet to another in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to build a tool that lets me insert a spreadsheet in a given format into sheet1. Then it takes some data and inserts it into a specified location in sheet2.

I am using functions in the following format at the moments:

```
=Sheet1!AI2
```

For every column, I need the data from all rows i.e sheet1 A1 to sheet2 B2, Sheets A2 to sheet B3 ...

There are hundreds of rows and I don't want to copy-paste it and manually change the row number.

Is there a way to do it like this:

```
=Sheet1!AI(rownumber-1)
```

That way it would work for all rows.

Thanks for taking the time and reading this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting this in `Sheet2!B2`

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(Sheet1!AI:AI)
```

or this (it will give you the same result):

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!AI:AI)
```

Be sure that `Sheet2` has at leas one more row than `Sheet1`. Google Sheets will automatically add 500 new rows, but if the numbers of rows in those sheets are codependent than rows will be added in a loop up until the limit.

Comment: Amazing mate! Worked so well. Exactly what I needed. You are an absolute legend!

Comment: Glad to help. Take care comrade!

Comment: When I use the solution I also get the first row of the column. is there a way to exclude it?

Comment: Sure. Use `Sheet1!AI2:AI` instead of `Sheet1!AI:AI`. Like this: `=INDEX(Sheet1!AI2:AI)`.